# Error : Could not read image in Google Colab

Tags: python, computer-vision, google-colaboratory

I am following this tutorial to build a custom-made object detection model on Detect.

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/simplest-way-to-do-object-detection-on-custom-datasets/

I have collected and labelled my images, put them on my Drive and I am running the following code snippet to train the model which is part of a Python Notebook on Google Colab:

```
Train_dataset = core.Dataset('/content/drive/My Drive/training model/Training',transform=custom_transforms)#L1
Test_dataset = core.Dataset('/content/drive/My Drive/training model/Test')#L2

loader=core.DataLoader(Train_dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True)#L3

model = core.Model(['black car', 'grey car','white truck'])#L4

losses = model.fit(loader, Test_dataset, epochs=25, lr_step_size=5, learning_rate=0.001, verbose=True)#L5
plt.plot(losses)
plt.show()
```

However, I keep getting the following error shortly after the first model epoch starts :

```
ValueError: Could not read image /content/drive/My Drive/training model/Training/frame22.jpg
```

It gives this error randomly, not only with frame22 but with other frames also that are not present in this directory. I tried to remount my Drive with enabling force_remount at the beginning of the script, but the error persists.

Comment: When you create a Dataset object, it is a sort of index of your data. Then the dataloader is a tool to take n instance in the dataset (here n=2, it is the batch_size) and return them in a specific format with their annotations for the model to learn. Based on the error message, it suggests your Dataset index has the item frame22 but the actual object is not there. I don't know the Detecto implementation of Dataset but I would think you have an annotation for frame22 and no image.

Comment: My question is more related to Google Colab maybe. For example, this error had been shown for other images too which used to exist in that directory, but I renamed them (so from frame10_(1) to frame100001 for example). I thought if there is something related to cache or memory, so it keeps trying to look for files which don't exist anymore.

Comment: I don't think it is linked to Colab. If you rename the file, you need to rename both the image and the xml. But also the name of the image **inside** the xml. That is probably what triggered your error. If you renamed the image after the labelling, your xml still has the old image name as one of its key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the code of the `core.Dataset` implementation from Detecto and I confirm what I said in my comments.

The index is created by getting all the `.xml` annotation files and creating an index that maps them to their image. It does not check that the image is actually there.

For the image filename, it uses the one that is **inside** the `xml` file, not the name of the `xml` file. See below a view of an annotation XML file, where you see the `filename` attribute. If you change the name of your image, you need to change it inside the `xml` file.

[image: annotation_xml]

Comment: Thanks. Apparently that was the issue.

Regarding the training on the test data comment, the implementation of Detecto in this case is done such a way that the validation is done on the test data with that code line, according to Detecto documentation.

Comment: Glad to hear it works. I removed my comments on the training on test data, I read too fast and didn't see it was just using it as validation as you said! Thanks for making me discover Detecto though it seems like a great Pytorch toolbox!